# Two triangles $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle BDE$ are placed in a way that $B$ is the right-angle of both. Find the measurement of the $\angle BDE$.

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, contest-math, triangles, alternative-proof

**Source:** *Regional Math Olympiad of BD.*

> In the given diagram, both $\angle ABC$ and $\angle DBE$ are right-angled triangles. $B$ is the right angle for both (according to the diagram). They have hypotenuses $AC$ and $DE$ of the same length and $F$ is the middle point of both the hypotenuse. $DE$ is perpendicular to $BC$. Area of $\triangle ABC$ is $\sqrt 3$ times of $DEF$. What is the value of angle $\angle BDE$?

Here is a likelier figure of the contextual problem:

[image]

At first, I thought $DEF$ meant $DE+EF$. Therefore, $DE$ + $\frac{1}{2} DE$ = $\frac {3}{2} DE$. As it is mentioned in the above post that $AC= DE$, so $\frac {3}{2} DE$ = $\frac{3}{2} AC$.

Let us denote the angle $\angle ACB$ = $\theta$

From another condition, we can write that:

$\frac{1}{2} AB × BC$ = $\frac {3 \sqrt 3}{2} AC$.

$AB×BC$ = $3 \sqrt 3 AC$

And then, dividing with $BC$ to both side, we get:

$AB$ = $\frac {3 \sqrt 3 C}{BC}$

$AB$ = $3 \sqrt 3 \sec\theta$ (by denoting $\angle ACB$ as $\theta$)

Here is the problem. I failed to show any relation of $\theta$ with $AB$. I don't know whether I'm approaching towards the right direction or not. If not so, then please help me find my mistake.

*Kindly pardon my error. Thanks in advance.*

*And if you correct my mistake, then I'll very much glad.*

Comment: Where is triangle DEF?

Comment: @greedoid That's so why I'm little bit confused and disturbed. I can see that $D, E and F$  are collinear. I didn't understand the fact. This problem was appeared in a math contest. So I don't know so much about it. But there can be another way but I ain't so sure about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replace the alleged $\triangle DEF$ by $\triangle DEB$.

Let $|FG|=:h$, $|BG|=:s$, and let $r$ be the radius of the circle with center $F$ going through $A$, $B$, E$, C$, and $D$. Then ${\rm area}(ABC)=\sqrt{3}\>{\rm area}(DEB)$ implies $2hs=\sqrt{3}rs$, so that together with $h^2+s^2=r^2$ we obtain
$$\angle(BFG)=\arctan{s\over h}={1\over\sqrt{3}}=30^\circ\ .$$
This implies $\angle(BDG)=15^\circ$.

Comment: I was thinking so but not was sured. Maybe this could be. Thank you for your effort. I will check it out and later I'll inform you. But can't a triangle be $n$ times of a side of a distinctive triangle where $n$ is described as positive integer number? Then somehow we might have got the point that the area of $\triangle ABC$ is $\sqrt 3$ times of length $DEF$.